# Win Api Custom credential provider : Dialog box resizing after windows login

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, dialog, credential-providers

I have created my custom credential provider to login to windows with smart card. When I insert the smartcard the dialog box for entering pin appears as appropriate size but once I am logged in to the system, every time I lock and unlock the system, dialog box gets resized and remains the same size after that. It only gets the original size once system is restarted or signed in again.

Can you please help me to understand

1. why the coordinates are resized after login and remain resized with fixed size through out the user windows login session?
2. How to fix the size of the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the root cause  for this issue.

The default dpi of the system has scaling factor of 150%, i.e. dpi value 144, but GPO setting was overriding the registry value LogPixel to 96 and DesktopDPIOverride to -2(it should be 0 for default).
So before login when GPO setting is not applied, application was using default dpi of value 144, and dialogbox was rendring well, but once user is logged in to the system, GPO setting used to apply with dpi value 96, so dialogbox used to get reduced in size with factor of 50%.

To solve this problem we do following :

```
1)Create new GPO setting with system Default DPI values
2)Make your application DPI aware
```